# I want to call a function immediately as the user select any item from dropdown on page postback how to do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#subtypes.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SubitemID"))).title%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("quantity")%></td>
                        <td><%#ThanaRecord.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Thanaid"))).title%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("created_at")%></td>
                        <td> <% if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "Admin") { %>
                            <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=update&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">EDIT</a>

                                <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=delete&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">DELETE</a>
                            <% } %>
                        <%if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "SuperVisor")
                           { %>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="120px"  AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="form-control">
                     <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="0">Status</asp:ListItem>
                              <asp:ListItem Text="Accept" Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>

                            <%--<asp:textbox runat="server" id="textTest"></asp:textbox>--%>
                        </td>
                        <%} %>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
CODE:
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)sender;
        //string SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList ddldrop = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            int  value =Convert.ToInt32( ddldrop.SelectedValue);
            Supervisor sup = new Supervisor();
        if (value == 1) {
                sup.Status = "Accept";
                sup.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `AutoPostBack` has to be `True` for the event handler to fire immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add **SelectedIndexChanged** event and set **AutoPostBack** to True on your **dropdownlist** control.

Then in code behind add following code and just exclude the **ScriptManager** part and use your method to store or display any where u like.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        RepeaterItem rptItems = ddl.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
        DropDownList ddlItems = rptItems.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "showname", "javascript: alert('" + ddlItems.SelectedItem.ToString()   + "');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement an SelectedIndexChanged event and set AutoPostBack to True.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
                  runat="server" 
                  Width="120px"  
                  AutoPostBack="false" 
                  CssClass="form-control">
```

To:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
                  runat="server" 
                  Width="120px"  
                  AutoPostBack="true" 
                  CssClass="form-control"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged>
```

Code Behind:

```
// event handler - this event will fire for ALL drop downs in the repeater
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // this will tell which drop down fired the event
  var dropdown = (DropDownList)sender;
  // this will tell you the repeater item containing the drop down
  var repeateritem = (RepeaterItem)dropdown.NamingContainer;
}
```

This fires the event immediately.

**NOTE:** 
This behaviour creates a `POST` which will fire `Page_Load`, if you call `DataBind()` on the repeater BEFORE the drop down list event has fired it will not fire at all. Make sure that `DataBind()` is guarded with `!IsPostback` to avoid supressing the event.

for example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = SomeDataSource; // whatever
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: But dropdownlist selected index  event will not find dropdown inside repeater

Comment: But how to find dropdown value inside repaeater in dropdown selected index change event?

Comment: @HishamShahid So glad I put in all this effort to help you and you mark another answer, even they are same and mine was first.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I understood that person code better and it work for me .

Comment: @HishamShahid no worries. It's your choice after all. It can just be frustrating sometimes. Especially when you're old and grumpy like me : )