# How to find dropdown selected value inside repeater in dropdown selected index change event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%#subtypes.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SubitemID"))).title%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("quantity")%></td>
                    <td><%#ThanaRecord.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Thanaid"))).title%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("created_at")%></td>
                    <td> <% if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "Admin") { %>
                        <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=update&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">EDIT</a>

                            <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=delete&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">DELETE</a>
                        <% } %>
                    <%if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "SuperVisor")
                       { %>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="120px"  AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="0">Status</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Accept" Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>

                        <%--<asp:textbox runat="server" id="textTest"></asp:textbox>--%>
                    </td>
                    <%} %>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)sender;
    //string SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddldrop = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        int  value =Convert.ToInt32( ddldrop.SelectedValue);
        Supervisor sup = new Supervisor();
    if (value ==1 ) {
            sup.Status = "Accept";
            sup.Save();
        }
    }
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Supervisor sup = new Supervisor();
    //sup.Status = "Accept";
    //sup.Save();
}
```

Comment: Have already gave you the solution in your previous post. Pls refer that and give it a shot  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217680/i-want-to-call-a-function-immediately-as-the-user-select-any-item-from-dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to cast the `sender` argument in the event-handler to `DropDownList`. It is  always the source of the event. So no need to use `FindControl`:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
   string selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
   // ...
}
```